# delete, arrows, and backspace not working in terminal when PWD is long

Tags: command-line, keyboard

i am trying to work on a folder with a very long path. 
i am trying to work on a folder with a very long path. 
when i write commands i can't delete them with backspace or delete.
the arrow key stop working too except the left key (i am working in a computer where arrow keys are also END, PgUp, PgDn, and Home)

#### the terminal where the keys don't work

[image: the terminal where the keys don't work]

when i move the same folder a few folders up everything works normally.
is this a bug? what is happening?

the PWD: `/home/ronen/Desktop/DevSecOps/week 1/git/task 2/git-day_2-git-excercises/training-instructor-master-chapter-2-git-day_2-git-excercises/chapter-2-git/day_2/git-excercises`

echo $PS1 output:
[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

echo $COLUMNS output:
80

shopt checkwinsize output:
checkwinsize    on

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `echo "$PS1"`, `echo $COLUMNS` and `shopt checkwinsize`

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using more limited shell like `sh` currently. You can check this with

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER
```

which will print you your config with the bash you are using at the end of the line. My guess your is `/bin/sh`

If you want to use more features, switch your shell to `/bin/bash` (or even other options like zsh if you have it) using `chsh` command.

you should have no issues with those keys with /bin/bash (I don't)

Comment: i knew i was using bash, but i checked anyway and this is my output : ronen:x:1000:1000:ronen,,,:/home/ronen:/bin/bash. did you try to recreate this?

Comment: So your problem starts when your command starts to become long enough to take more than one terminal line?

Comment: actually no, when i tried to make a long path in another folder it didn't happen... maybe something with the specific path?

Comment: i just tried the same path and it didn't happen but when i clipped the terminal to the side it happend...